# Segmentation Fault (Core Dump) - Code works in VS but not in the Linux Terminal

Tags: c++, linux, windows, segmentation-fault

So, I can run this program in Visual Studio with absolutely no problems, producing correct output. However, after compiling in the Linux terminal, I get a seg fault when trying to run the same code. Upon debugging using GDB, the information given is not very helpful (will be provided below). The program consists of two header files and three .cpp files. I will provide all of them below, along with the debugging information given. (If the indenting is weird, it is because of the 4-space code indent rule for submission). I have been trying to find the issue for hours on end to no avail. I have a feeling it is a small, minor mistake. Thank you all very much in advance.

**Song.h**

```
#ifndef Song_h
#define Song_h

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Song
{
private:
    string artist;
    string title;
    int size;

public:
    Song(); //declares blank song array

    Song(string _title, string _artist, int _size); //initializes object with given parameters for Song instance

    string getArtist() const
    {
        return artist;
    }

    string getTitle() const
    {
        return title;
    }

    int getSize() const
    {
        return size;
    }

    void setArtist(string _artist)
    {
        artist = _artist;
    }

    void setTitle(string _title)
    {
        title = _title;
    }

    void setSize(int _size)
    {
        size = _size;
    }


    bool operator == (Song const &rhs);

    bool operator != (Song const &rhs);

    bool operator > (Song const &rhs);

    bool operator < (Song const &rhs);

};

#endif
```

**TsuPod.h**

```
#ifndef TsuPod_h
#define TsuPod_h
#include "Song.h"

//TsuPod class declaration
class TsuPod
{
private:
struct SongNode
{
    Song data;
    SongNode *next;
};

SongNode *songs;  //the head pointer

static const int MAX_SIZE = 512;
static const int SUCCESS = 0;
static const int FAILURE = 1;
static const int NO_MEMORY = -1;
static const int NOT_FOUND = -2;
int getNumSongs();
int memSize;

public:
TsuPod();
TsuPod(int size);
~TsuPod();
int addSong(Song const &s);
int removeSong(Song const &s);
void shuffle();
void showSongList();
void sortSongList();
int getRemainingMemory();

int getTotalMemory() 
{
    return memSize;
}
};
```

**Song.cpp**

```
#endif

#include "TsuPod.h"
#include "Song.h"

Song::Song() //default constructor, initializes a blank song
{
artist = "";
title = "";
size = 0;
}

Song::Song(string _artist, string _title, int _size) //constructor for   song when arguments are given by user
{
artist = _artist;
title = _title;
size = _size;
}

bool Song::operator == (Song const &rhs) //overloaded for sorting
{
return (title == rhs.title &&
         artist == rhs.artist &&
         size == rhs.size);
}

bool Song::operator != (Song const &rhs) //overloaded for sorting
{
return (title != rhs.title ||
    artist != rhs.artist ||
    size != rhs.size);
}

bool Song::operator > (Song const &rhs) //overloaded for sorting
{
if (artist != rhs.artist)
    return (artist > rhs.artist);
else
if (title != rhs.title)
    return (title > rhs.title);
else
if (size != rhs.size)
    return (size > rhs.size);
else 
    return false;
}

bool Song::operator < (Song const &rhs) //overloaded for sorting
{
if (artist != rhs.artist)
    return (artist < rhs.artist);
else
if (title != rhs.title)
    return (title < rhs.title);
else
if (size != rhs.size)
    return (size < rhs.size);
else
    return false;

}
```

**TsuPod.cpp**

```
#include "TsuPod.h"
#include "Song.h"


TsuPod::TsuPod() //default constructor
{
memSize = MAX_SIZE;
}

TsuPod::TsuPod(int _size) //constructor for when user specifies their prefered memory size, prevents input of a size greater than MAX_SIZE or less than 0
{
if (_size > MAX_SIZE || _size <= 0)
    memSize = MAX_SIZE;
else
    memSize = _size;
}

TsuPod::~TsuPod() //destructor
{
SongNode *p;

while (songs != NULL)
{
    p = songs;
    songs = songs->next;
    delete p;   
}
}


int TsuPod::getRemainingMemory() //finds remaining memory, returns int value
{
int memSum = 0;
SongNode *p = songs;

while (p != NULL)
{
    memSum += p->data.getSize();
    p = p->next;
}
return memSize - memSum; 
}

int TsuPod::addSong(Song const &s) //adds song to TsuPod, returns int number to display result, 0 = success, 1 = failure, -1 = not enough memory
{
if (s.getSize() > getRemainingMemory()) //ensures there is enough unsused memory for song 
    return NO_MEMORY;

if (s.getSize() > 0) //ensures song is valid
{
    SongNode *temp = new SongNode;
    temp->data = s;
    temp->next = songs;
    songs = temp;
    return SUCCESS;
}

else
    return FAILURE;

}


int TsuPod::removeSong(Song const &s) //removes song, returns int value to display result, 0 = success, 1 = failure, -2 = not found
{
if (songs != NULL)
{
    SongNode *prev = NULL;
    SongNode *p = songs;

    if (p->data == s)
    {
        songs = p->next;
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    while (p != NULL && p->data != s)
    {
        prev = p;
        p = p->next;

        if (songs->data == s) 
        {
            songs = p->next;
            delete p;
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        else 
        if (p->data == s)
        {
            prev->next = p->next;
            delete p;
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }  
}
return NOT_FOUND;
}

int TsuPod::getNumSongs() //calculates number of songs, returns int value
{
SongNode *p1 = songs;
int i = 0;
while (p1 != NULL)
{
    i++;
    p1 = p1->next;
}

return i;
}

void TsuPod::shuffle() //shuffles TsuPod song list, void return value
{
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
for (int j = 0; j < getNumSongs() * 2; j++)
{   
    int r1 = rand() % getNumSongs();
    int r2 = rand() % getNumSongs();

    SongNode *p1 = songs;
    SongNode *p2 = songs;

    for (int i = 0; i < r1; i++)
        p1 = p1->next;

    for (int i = 0; i < r2; i++)
        p2 = p2->next;

    Song temp = p1->data;
    p1->data = p2->data;
    p2->data = temp;
}

cout << endl << " PLAYLIST SHUFFLED" << endl << endl;
}

void TsuPod::sortSongList() //sorts song list by artist, title, and size respectively, void return value
{
for (SongNode *p1 = songs; p1 != NULL; p1 = p1->next)
{
    SongNode *small = p1;
    for (SongNode *p2 = p1->next; p2 != NULL; p2 = p2->next)
    {
        if (small->data > p2->data)
        {
            small = p2;
        }
    }

    if (p1 != small)
    {
        Song temp = small->data;
        small->data = p1->data;
        p1->data = temp;
    }
}
cout << endl << " PLAYLIST SORTED" << endl;
}

void TsuPod::showSongList() //shows song list, void return value
{
cout << "             ___________________________________________________                  " << endl << "                                TsuPod 2.0" << endl << endl;
cout << "          Memory ----                 Total: " << getTotalMemory() << " MB" << "   --   Remaining: " << getRemainingMemory() << " MB" << endl;

SongNode *p = songs;
int i = 0;
while (p != NULL)
{
   i++;
    cout << endl << " " << i << ". " << p->data.getArtist();

    int artistLength = p->data.getArtist().length();
    for (int j = 0; j < (24 - artistLength); j++) //This loop is implemented to evenly space the artist from the song
        cout << " ";

    cout << p->data.getTitle();

    int titleLength = p->data.getTitle().length();
    for (int j = 0; j < (24 - titleLength); j++) //This loop is implemented to evenly space the song title from the song size
        cout << " ";

    cout << p->data.getSize() << " (MB)" << endl;

    p = p->next;
}

cout << endl;

}
```

**TsuPod_Driver.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Song.h"
#include "TsuPod.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
TsuPod t;

Song s1("Animals As Leaders", "Another Year", 4);
int result = t.addSong(s1);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s2("Gorillaz", "Stylo", 6);
result = t.addSong(s2);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s3("August Burns Red", "Meridian", 6);
result = t.addSong(s3);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s4("The Ink Spots", "If I Didn't Care", 7);
result = t.addSong(s4);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s5("Beatles", "I Feel Fine", 241);
result = t.addSong(s5);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s6("Fine Constant", "Sea", 3);
result = t.addSong(s6);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s7("Human Abstract", "Nocturne", 9);
result = t.addSong(s7);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s8("August Burns Red", "Meridian", 4);
result = t.addSong(s8);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;

Song s9("Frank Sinatra", "My Way", 5);
result = t.addSong(s9);
cout << " add result = " << result << endl;



t.showSongList();   
t.shuffle();
t.showSongList();
t.sortSongList();
t.showSongList();


result = t.removeSong(s1);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s2);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s3);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

t.showSongList();

result = t.removeSong(s4);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s5);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s6);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s7);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s8);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

result = t.removeSong(s9);
cout << " delete result = " << result << endl;

t.showSongList();

cout << " memory = " << t.getRemainingMemory() << endl << endl << endl << endl;

for (int i = 1; i < 33; i++) //tests to ensure that user cannot add a song when there is not enough space available 
{
    Song s1("August Burns Red", "Meridian", i);
    result = t.addSong(s1);
    cout << " add result = " << result << endl;
}

t.showSongList();

cin.get();
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

**Debugging Info From Linux Terminal**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402d50 in Song::getSize() const ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x0000000000402d50 in Song::getSize() const ()
#1  0x00000000004024ac in TsuPod::getRemainingMemory() ()
#2  0x00000000004024fb in TsuPod::addSong(Song const&) ()
#3  0x000000000040112e in main ()
```

Comment: The information given by gdb *is* helpful. It is telling you the crash happen when calling `getSize()` in `getRemainingMemory()`. So next, you should put a breakpoint on `getRemainingMemory()`. And examine all the variables there. Particularly pointers, as segfaults happen when they are uninitialized ...

Comment: @Leiaz The only reason I had interpreted the information as not being useful was that this was my first time using GDB and was expecting more info (line numbers). But I definitely see what you mean now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It prints the line numbers if you compiled with debugging symbols (`-g` option for g++).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any sign of TsuPod::songs being initialized. There is no guarantee that it's going to be NULL in the empty list case, so your

```
while (p != NULL)
```

test in TsuPod::getRemainingMemory() may pass with an insane value from the stack and blow up when you use p on the next line.

I recommend

```
TsuPod::TsuPod():songs(NULL) //default constructor
{
memSize = MAX_SIZE;
}

TsuPod::TsuPod(int _size):songs(NULL) //constructor for when user specifies their prefered memory size, prevents input of a size greater than MAX_SIZE or less than 0
{
if (_size > MAX_SIZE || _size <= 0)
    memSize = MAX_SIZE;
else
    memSize = _size;
}
```

to ensure that songs starts with your end of list condition.

Also, consider using std::list to do your list management in place of the roll-your-own linked list.

Comment: Thank you very much! I hope you don't mind if I ask another question (I'm still relatively new to pointers). Your solution worked, but why is declaring the head 'songs' as NULL in the constructor different from just declaring 'songs' NULL in the class declaration?

Comment: I'm not up on my C++11 or 14, I don't think the standard allows you to make assignments in the class definition. All a declaration is guaranteed to do is reserve space, and everything after that is up to you. My understanding is Visual Studio's compiler is being nice and initializing everything to zero, but virtually all of the time the coder's going to set that value to something so pre-emptively zeroing is wasted effort.